# Python finding a value in a list of lists

Tags: python, list

Recently I had to find which list something was in. I used:

```
def findPoint(haystack, needle): # haystack = [[1,2,3], [4,5]...,[6,7,8,9]]
    for x in range(len(haystack)):
        if needle in haystack[x]:
            return x
    raise Exception("needle: " + str(needle) + " not in haystack")
```

There is a haystack.index(needle) method.
The question is: "Is there a better way to do this?"

Comment: I was using the index in another function like this.  

`if index1 != index2: haystack[index1].extend(haystack.pop(index2))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, no need for range, for starters

```
for hay in haystack:
  if needle in hay:
    return hay
```

And if you really really need the index, use `enumerate`

```
for x, hay in enumerate(haystack):
  if needle in hay:
    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this with a 1-liner:

```
def find_point(haystack,needle)
    return next(elem for elem in haystack if needle in elem)
```

I think should work (but it returns the haystack element).  This raises a `StopIteration` if the needle isn't in any of the haystack elements.

It doesn't sound like you actually need the index, but if you do, use `enumerate` (as proposed by the excellent answer by Dima Rudnik):

```
def find_point(haystack,needle):
    return next(idx for idx,elem in enumerate(haystack) if needle in elem)
```